# Reading existing rows from a database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

The application I am developing is meant to be a quick and easy tool to import data to our main app. So the user loads in a `CSV`, meddles with the data a little and pushes it up to the database.

Before the data is pushed to the database, I have a verification check going on which basically says, "Does a customer exist in the database with the same name, account and sort codes? If so, put their guid (which is known already) into a list."

The problem is, the result variable is always 0; this is despite the fact that there is duplicate test data already in my database which should show a result. Added to that, using `SQL Profiler`, I can't see a query actually being executed against the database.

I'm sure that the `ExecuteScalar()` is what I should be doing, so my attention comes to the Parameters I'm adding to the SqlCommand... but I'll be blowed if I can figure it... any thoughts?

```
string connectionString = Generic.GetConnectionString("myDatabase");
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("select COUNT(*) from Customers C1 INNER JOIN CustomerBank B1 ON C1.Id = B1.CustomerId WHERE C1.Name = @Name AND B1.SortCode = @SortCode AND B1.AccountNumber = @AccountNumber", conn);
                    foreach (DataRow row in importedData.Rows)
                    {
                        check.Parameters.Clear();
                        check.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = row["Name"].ToString();
                        check.Parameters.Add("@SortCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = row["SortCode"].ToString();
                        check.Parameters.Add("@AccountNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = row["AccountNumber"].ToString();

                        Object result = check.ExecuteScalar();
                        int count = (Int32)result;

                        if (count > 0)
                        {
                            DuplicateData.Add((Guid)row["BureauCustomerId"]);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Clarification: `importedData` is a `DataTable` of the user's data held in this `C#` application. During the `ForEach` loop, each row has various columns, a few of those being `Name`, `SortCode` and `AccountNumber`. The values seem to get set in the parameters (but will verify now).

Comment: Code is not complete. What is row["xxx"] and  hard to say, what gives ToString()

Comment: what happens if you step through are you sure those values are what you think they are?

Comment: Have updated the question with the above info. The ToString() part was just part of my efforts to get it working and may not be correct. Have removed them for now.

Comment: Your code looks correct, have you tried to execute your query in sql management studio and check if you get the expected result? have you debuged the code to check the value of the passed parameters?

Comment: So you are querying a database in a loop for each row of your file? For any dataset of a reasonable size this will be horribly slow.

Comment: This isn't a regular thing. It will be used initially for around 800 rows, and then maybe once a month with about 60 rows. The speed isn't an issue as this functionality will be added to the main product in a much better guise. We just happen to have a customer about to go live who need this as a quick and dirty solution, speed is irrelevant as this app will be trashed within a few months.

Comment: You tested your sql in ssms to verify its voracity?  Err. Veracity.

Comment: Yep, returns the exact data I want. I see where the app is logging into my database using sql server profiler just fine, however I do not see the query being run at all... I have run our main product up and seen its traces just fine, so the profiler must be set up correctly.

Comment: If you don't see the query in profiler, you may be connecting to the wrong database.